# input and button misalignment

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to align an input box and button.

Without bootstrap css framework it works fine, however, when I add bootstrap the search button is misaligned.

```
.container{
    height: 120px;
}
input, button{
    height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1am8uqwu/1/

I've figured out some fixes, but I wanted to understand the fundamentals of why this is happening.

My Fixes:

1. I found the fix below particularly interesting, as the input and button  elements have no padding to begin with. lolwut?

   ```
   input, button{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }
   ```
2. .

   ```
   input, button{
     vertical-align: middle or top
   }
   ```

*Note the misalignment is subtle

Comment: What do you mean by misaligned? Looking at your jsfiddle, the button is perfectly aligned to the input field. Please elaborate.

Comment: It is subtle, if you look closely, the button is a few pixels below the input box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button seems to have default padding, and lines up with the input box when its padding is set to 0.

https://jsfiddle.net/1am8uqwu/14/

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
    height: 120px;
}

input, button{
    height: 100%;
}

button {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn, this fixes it. I don't understand why this works, as I have box-sizing: border-box. Both the elements are still the same height.

Answer (score 0):

You have your button and input wrapped around a `.container` div element.

With bootstrap this causes the below styles to be applied:

```
.container { 
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Thus centering the content inside of the container with the `auto` attribute.
Without bootstrap the style is not applied and the content it not centered.

View the docs for more info: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Comment: @sebko No problem, what is wrong with the above fiddle, do you want the button aligned underneath the input box ?

Comment: Unfortunately they are still vertically misaligned. It is very subtle!

Comment: I've just tested in a windows environment and it looks fine. Must have something to do with how mac applies styling to these elements